# How to synchronise '.append()' and ajax query within 'for' loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, asynchronous

Good day, everyone! It seems like I have asynchronous actions issue which I cannot figure out how to handle.

I expect this code to show

> Category 1,
>
> Items of category 1
>
> Category 2,
>
> Items of category 2
>
> Category 3,
>
> Items of category 3

Instead of it what I get is:

> Category 1,
>
> Category 2,
>
> Category 3,
>
> Items of category 1
>
> Items of category 2
>
> Items of category 3

Here is the code:

```
function showSubheadersMenu (items) {
    for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      $("#gallery").append($("<div id=" + items[j].id + " class=\"gallery-item\"><div class=\"item-img\" style=\"background-image:url(" + items[j].better_featured_image.source_url + ")\"></div></div>"));
    }
  }

 function showSingleCategory (subheader) {
    $("#gallery").append($("<h3 class=\"subcat\">" + subheader.name + "</h3>"));

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + subheader.id + "",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "GET",

      success: showSubcategoryItems, // Show items in subcategory

      error: handleAjaxError
   });
 }

if (subheaders.length > 0) { //If there are subcategories
   for (i = 0; i < subheaders.length; i++) {
     showSingleCategory(subheaders[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping the `$("#gallery").append($("<h3>(...)</h3>"));` inside the success function

Comment: can you include `showSubcategoryItems` to here?

Comment: @agrm it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to ajax's asynchronism, all the 'success' calls are guaranteed to happen after all the `<h3>` elements have been appended. Hence the symptom you describe.

This is simple to overcome by keeping a reference to the header element and inserting after it whatever is composed by `showSubcategoryItems(data)`.

```
function showSingleCategory (subheader) {
    // keep reference to the appended <h3>
    var $header = $("<h3 class=\"subcat\">" + subheader.name + "</h3>").appendTo("#gallery");

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + subheader.id + "",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            // Show items in subcategory after the corresponding header
            $(showSubcategoryItems(data)).insertAfter($header),
        }
        error: handleAjaxError
    });
}

if (subheaders.length > 0) { //If there are subcategories
    for (i = 0; i < subheaders.length; i++) {
        showSingleCategory(subheaders[i]);
    }
}
```

And `showSubcategoryItems()` will be of this general form :

```
function showSubcategoryItems(data) {
    var html = .....; // compose html from data
    return html;
}
```

By appending the headers synchronously, their order is guaranteed to be congruous with the original `subheaders` regardless of the order in which the ajax responses are received.

Answer (score 3):

Try appending the `<h3>` *inside* of your success callback. That way, it will append each header at the same time as its respective items, giving you the desired output.

```
function showSingleCategory (subheader) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + subheader.id + "",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "GET",

      success: function (data) {
        $("#gallery").append($("<h3 class=\"subcat\">" + subheader.name + "</h3>"));
        showSubcategoryItems(data);
      }, // Show items in subcategory

      error: handleAjaxError
   });
}

if (subheaders.length > 0) { //If there are subcategories
   for (i = 0; i < subheaders.length; i++) {
     showSingleCategory(subheaders[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for writing a solution! It helped me a lot!

Comment: @AlexanderPrisazhny No problem! Glad it helped =)

Comment: Yes kind of, except that the ajax responses are not guaranteed to arrive back in the same order as the requests. If it is important to retain the original order, then don't do it this way.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 True. Good solution you posted. +1'd

Comment: @AlexanderPrisazhny You should check Roamer's solution - it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @mhodges, you are a kind and generous person.